# Does referring to an object makes different in memory usage

Tags: java, oop, memory-management

I have this two codes:

```
A a = new A();
B b = a.getB();
```

```
B b = new A().getB();
```

In the first code I created two objects and **saved** them so the program need memory for two objects.
But in the second code I created object from A and I **didn't** saved it in any variable so my question is :
what is the different between this two codes? is it just a syntax or there is an effect on memory?

Comment: There is a slight difference, in that `a` can only be garbage collected once it goes out of scope; but there is still memory allocated for an `A` in the second case, you just have no means of referring to it again (and the scope of the `A` is the statement; so it can be GC'd after the statement completes).

Comment: But really: don't worry about the difference. Use the one you find most readable.

Comment: All the answers here (so far at least) are wrong about one thing: object lifetime is not tied to scope. An object becomes unreachable once there is no longer any code path forward that can interact with the object. This can happen while a variable that references the object is still in scope. As soon as the object becomes unreachable, it is eligible for GC. It may be reclaimed instantly (if the JIT optimizes it to), or it may be reclaimed at some time in the future. A smart enough JIT may even elide the allocation entirely if it can inline all the methods you call on the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reference/Pointer versus Object

Your term "saved" has no technical meaning, and may be confusing you.

Let’s get more concrete. Replace `A` class with `Cat` class. Replace `B` class with `Breed` class.

Let's assume that when instantiating a `Cat` we also instantiate a `Breed` object held within that `Cat` object. In other words, we are *not* doing [lazy-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) in this example. So when instantiating a `Cat`, we pass along an instance of `Breed` to the constructor.

### Two lines

The `Cat a` variable does not hold a `Cat` object, it holds a reference (a pointer) to the `Cat` object that was constructed elsewhere in memory. That location of the `Cat` object in memory, basically a number, is what is held by the `Cat a`.

```
Cat a = new Cat( "Fluffy" , new Breed( "Tabby" ) ) ;  Passing new instance of `Breed` to constructor of `Cat`, with resulting `Cat` object’s location in memory being returned to the `a` reference/pointer variable.
```

You can think of that line of code as this:

```
Pointer-holding-memory-location-of-object-of-class-Cat a = Instantiate-a-new-Cat-object-somewhere-in-memory-and-return-its-memory-location( … ) ;
```

Conceptual diagram:

[image]

Notice that the only way to access the `Breed` object is to go through the `Cat` object `Fluffy`. The only way our code can get to that `Cat` object is through the reference/pointer variable named `a`.

```
Breed b = a.getBreed() ;  // Accessing the `Cat` instance, then traversing to the `Breed` object.
```

After that code we have wee bit of memory now allocated to holding another pointer/reference, the variable named `b`. The `b` variable is not `Cat` nor a `Breed`, it is the memory location of where to find the `Breed` object elsewhere in memory. We can now directly access the `Breed` object, without going through the `Cat` instance.

Conceptual diagram:

[image]

### One line

Your other code:

```
B b = new A().getB() ;
```

…converted to our example:

```
Breed b = new Cat( "Fluffy" , new Breed( "Tabby" ) ).getBreed() ;
```

…is quite similar, but never establishes the reference `a` as a named variable. The reference *is* generated, at least conceptually (in actuality a JVM may have optimizations). The brief ephemeral reference is used to immediately call the `getBreed` method.

After obtaining a memory-location of the `Breed` object, the ephemeral reference to the new `Cat` object is released, and the new `Cat` object falls out of scope. The new `Cat` object technically is likely still floating in memory for a moment, becoming a candidate for [garbage-collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), due to be purged from memory.

Of course the new one-liner seen above using `Cat` and `Breed` becomes silly: We instantiate a new `Breed`, pass it to the constructor of `Cat`, and then immediately ask to get it back. Let’s ignore the awkward silliness for the sake of this memory-management discussion.

Conceptual diagram:

[image]

As for memory management, the same amount of memory is likely taken in both your scenarios (depending on your JVM implementation). Both scenarios are establishing a pair of objects and a pair of references. The one slight difference is that in your second scenario the `Cat` object and its ephemeral pointer **go out of scope immediately**, and become candidates for garbage-collection. So memory *might* be reclaimed sooner than in your first scenario. In practice, the difference would likely be insignificant.

## Do not micro-optimize

As others commented, all this is merely academic. You generally should not worry about such micro-optimizations.

The modern compilers and JVMs are extremely well-optimized, some of the most well-optimized and well-tested large software projects ever. So the best way to write Java code is simply. Write simple easy-to-read and easy-to-understand code for humans, and you will also be writing code that is most likely to be well-optimized by the compiler and JVM. Trying to be clever by out-thinking the compiler & JVM is ironically liable to be counter-productive, resulting is less-optimized code.

Answer (score 3):

For light objects, very few differences.
In the first code the A object is assigned to a variable. So it is eligible to be garbage collected only as the variable is out of the scope.
In the second code the A object is not assigned to a variable. So it is right now eligible to be garbage collected.
In a general way you should not worry about this kind of things and using a variable or not using it only if it makes sense.

Comment: Unless object B has an internal reference to object A, which is entirely possible.  Also, who knows what is going on in object A.  There could be some static list that all instances of A are added to.

Comment: @aglassman yes, I was imprecise in my comments above. You could perhaps say "potentially eligible".

Answer (score 1):

You kinda answered your own question. In the first example, you created two variables 'A' and 'B' so more memory is used. In the second example, you only created on variable B, so less memory is used. In the second example, a new 'A' is created then the newly object calls the method getB() and the result is stored in the variable 'B'. In this situation the memory difference is very minimal, but if this was repeated multiple times over the course of a program then the memory usage could stack up.

Also, Java has its own garbage collector and when it runs it collects/deleted the memory of the objects that are no longer accessible. Once a variable goes out of scope, then the garbage collection can run and clean up that unused memory.
With the garage collector in place, the memory difference in the two statements almost does not matter.